# Watir: Can I open the file explorer from file_fields?

Tags: ruby, watir

So I know I can add a filepath to a file element type using Watir, but is it possible to open up the file explorer to select a file to upload? Or is the only way to just enter the path using .file_fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem? What do you want to do?

This will open file upload popup and select a file:

```
browser.file_field(:id, "the_file").set("C:\\image.png")
```

More information: [File Uploads](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/File+Uploads)